# Conflict with ROS Python and Conda

Tags: ros, bashrc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ever since I have installed Conda, ROS does not seem to work. And predictably it is because Conda has changed my Python environment.

I run ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

Can someone guide on how can I use both on my machine? I am willing to make changes to my system every time I want to switch from one to another.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244644/conflict-with-ros-python-and-conda/) by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2016-09-27

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that Conda is now in your path before system python (for which you probably have installed ros libraries).
In their [troubleshooting section](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/troubleshooting.html) check the section *Issue: Programs fail due to invoking conda Python and not system Python* : they suggest few solutions, the simplest of which is to remove conda from the path, and use conda later on with the full path names (such as *~/miniconda3/bin/conda*)

---

Originally posted by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) with karma: 526 on 2016-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rohin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26768/rohin/) on 2016-09-30**:
Thanks! That did it...should've looked into the troubleshooting guide before...

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-10-01**:
welcome! mark then the question as resolved to close it